# How can i use an imported collada file, as a soft body

Tags: animation, physics, import, soft-body

I'm currently trying to make a photo scans of a guy get hit by a car in blender, but I can't get the car or the guy to work as soft bodies. This is what blender shows me under the physics tab:
[image]

Both the car and the guy are imported models.
This image above is shon for both the guy and car.
The man is also rigged.

Comment: Is this a mesh object?

Comment: Yes this is a mesh object.